# Can you use Festool dust extraction with non-Festool tools?

Tags: tools, dust-collection

I'm looking into HEPA vacuums and dust extractors and I found Festool. Does anyone know whether we can attach non-Festool tools to their dust extractors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is not a problem however you won't get the anti-static properties. Depending on the tool you might need an adapter to match the tools dust port size.

Comment: How does the anti-static feature work? Can we hack the system to give us anti-static features?

Comment: Their system relies on hoses and connectors with a high carbon percentage so that they conduct electricity well enough to ground the hose.